# gphoto2 - GUI and save settings?

Tags: gphoto2

Just discovered gphoto2 2.5.15 on Ubuntu 18.04, and it connects to my camera - and this works:

```
$ gphoto2 --list-all-config
/main/actions/focuslock                                                        
Label: Focus Lock
Readonly: 0
Type: TOGGLE
Current: 2
END
/main/actions/opcode
Label: PTP Opcode
Readonly: 0
Type: TEXT
Current: 0x1001,0xparam1,0xparam2
END
...
```

So I looked through `man gphoto2`, but I cannot find how you could save some or all of these settings to a file, and how could you load settings from that file back on the camera. Can gphoto2 do it, and if not, are there other programs that can?

Also, there is a *ton* of those settings, quite hard to read them on terminal, GUI would really make sense. But the only GUI I found for this kind of config was:

```
sudo apt install python3-gphoto2
git clone https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2.git
cd python-gphoto2
python3 ./examples/camera-config-gui.py
```

... but the problem with it is, it apparently does not have scrollbars, and yet tries to fit all of the above properties on one page/tab, and as a result, is *extremely* long - I have to alt-drag it 2 or 3 times across monitor height to see the final buttons; also, once you click the apply settings button, it exits; and does not save/load settings either. Is there  another GUI for gphoto2 config, which would also just display what gphoto2 reports for --list-all-config, and allow their manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently darktable - which I saw, but I got confused that it had only a few of the camera parameters; then I saw https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/camera_settings.html and got even more confused, because it showed some properties that my darktable didn't show, but my camera had according to `gphoto2 --list-all-config`. And it turns out - you can add all/any of the settings manually, by clicking that very missable circle:

[image: darktable]

... right next to "property" under "additional property" under "properties". Also, my camera didn't want to accept most parameters until I set it to manual mode, which I could only find and do in `camera-config-gui.py`